# Flexbox children height follow specific children

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it's possible to make all flexbox children to follow the height of a specific child and hide their overflow if needed? The specific child should grow depending on it's content.

So this is the current situation:

[image]

And this is what I want (I specified the height for the image):

[image]

So is it possible to achieve this without js and without specifying height of any containers explicitly?

Comment: Position the red element absolute …? (Not sure how well that would work within a flexbox setting, but then again maybe it doesn’t need flexbox this way?)

Comment: @CBroe how to hide it's overflow then? As it's impossible to hide the overflow of a position absolute element. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hide the overflow of the parent container (the size of which will be determined by the blue element left in normal flow.) Or position at top:0 and bottom:0, and then hide the overflow of the element itself.

Comment: But the red container is absolutely positioned so it's parent container would not dictate it's overflow property correctly, no?

Comment: If the red element overflows the container (which it will do, when absolutely positioned from top, and higher than the actual container content), and you hide the overflow of that container - then you should have what you want. Or, as mentioned, the other way around, by making the red element full height (by setting top _and_ bottom), and then cutting off any overflow _that_ might have.

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry, but I am unable follow your answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/61yk782g/ - uncomment `/*overflow: hidden;*/` on the container element, and see what effect that has …

Comment: @CBroe Yesss! I was missing position relative on the parent. Your solution works like a charm! If you want - answer the question, I'll be glad to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just position the red element absolute. (Not sure how well that would work within a flexbox setting, but then again maybe it doesn’t need flexbox this way?)

Hide the overflow of the parent container (the size of which will be determined by the blue element left in normal flow.)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
}

.blue-child {
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="blue-child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
</div>
```

Or position at top:0 and bottom:0, and then hide the overflow of the element itself.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.red-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
}

.blue-child {
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="blue-child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
</div>
```